# how can I prevent class and its members from being tree shaken?

Tags: dart, dart2js

I would like to make sure that a class and all its members are not tree shaken when compiled with Dart2JS.

There used to be a `MirrorsUsed` annotation but that is long gone.

Anyway to do that nowadays without having to create an object of the class and using its members?

Maybe a `Pragma` annotation?

Comment: I still see the MirrorsUsed annotation in the docs for the latest version of Dart. May I ask what you're trying to achieve here? You could always just disable optimization if you don't want tree shaking.

Comment: Dart2JS doesn't compile the file if it sees the import of dart:mirrors. I am doing some tests with webcomponents and Dart

Comment: Ah yes, I see it's deprecated. Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: I've found few ways to work with webcomponents and one of them I would need that some methods should not be tree shaken and also retain their original names. I thought there would be a pragma or another annotation for that

Comment: It seems like you want JS interop. Look into that instead.

Comment: unfortunately Dart is not ready for webcomponents with JS interop